# Can I define a block of code in Perl?

Tags: perl

Just like a `#define` (preprocessor directive) in C, is there any way to define a block of code in perl.

```
use constant PI=>3.14;
```

Like this I can define only variable.
Can I do the same with a block of code?

The following code part does not work. How can I achieve the same?

```
use constant FUN=>{
$i=3;
while($i)
{
    print "$i\n";--$i;}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Perl doesn't have macros. (A sufficiently demented programmer could fake them using source filters but that sort of black magic is best avoided.) `use constant` doesn't trigger an inline replacement the way the C preprocessor does. Instead, it creates a subroutine that always returns the same value. When you write

```
use constant PI => 3.14;
```

what Perl does is (essentially)

```
sub PI() { 3.14 }
```

The `constant` pragma can only be used to define values, not code. To reuse code define a subroutine instead.

Comment: Perl has macros; see `Devel::Declare`.

Answer (score 2):

Most people would write that (give or take the positioning of braces) as:

```
sub FUN
{
    my $i = 3;
    while ($i)
    {
        print "$i\n";
        --$i;
    }
}
```

You could do:

```
my $FUN = sub { print "$_\n" foreach (qw(3 2 1)); };
&$FUN();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sub` keyword to define a function. 
Unlike C langage preprocessing is almost useless in scripting language such as perl.

Comment: Well, it's not like the C preprocessor is mainly used for defining inline functions... plus, even nearly all compiled languages get along without preprocessor :)

Comment: sub is fine but i was checking if preprocessor is allowed like C.

Comment: Implementing try catch mechanism. Where i was trying if catch code section can be embedded in the code itself rather than calling subroutine.

Comment: Don't invent your own try/catch. Use Try::Tiny (http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Try::Tiny) instead.

Comment: Your question is an [XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341). You'll get better answers if you ask about -- or at least tell us about -- your root problem (try/catch) instead of problems with your approach (macros).

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack but you can use string eval to achieve runtime evaluation of code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $code = "
my \$value = 17;
print \"\$value\n\";
" ;

eval $code ;
```

result:

```
[pt@localhost bin]$ perl testit2
17
[pt@localhost bin]$
```

You'll need mad escaping skills if you write anything complicated.
Update: if you use q() instead of " then much less escaping will be needed.

Answer (score -1):

Try/catch in perl can be implemented this way:

```
eval {
  # do something
  die "Exception1\n" if $something_not_right;
};
if ($@) {
  for ($@) {
    /Exception1/ && do { handle_excp1(); last; };
    /Exception2/ && do { handle_excp2(); last; };
    die "Don't know how to handle $@\n";
  };
};
```

Of course you don't have to use a string literal to throw an exception. Any object reference would do.